# HTML value not recognized in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My html input number value is not recognized in my J.S code, it alerts Nothing.. the same thing happens if i want to make another code

```js
var age = document.getElementById("ent").value;

document.getElementById("press").onclick = function() {
  alert(age);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="ent">
<button id="press">seed</button>
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. Can you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: You are storing the value of the input when the page loads, before the user types in a value to that input.

Comment: Move `var age = document.getElementById("ent").value;` inside the onclick event handler, should fix it. Storing it outside will set the value on load, which would be nothing.

Answer (score 7):

You're setting `age` when the page is first loaded, not after the user fills in the input. Assign the variable in the click handler.

```js
document.getElementById("press").onclick = function() {
  var age = document.getElementById("ent").value;
  alert(age);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="ent">
<button id="press">seed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> <head> <title>Quick Coding</title> </head> <body> <input type="number" id="ent"> <button id="press">seed</button> <script type="text/javascript">  document.getElementById("press").onclick = function(){ var age = document.getElementById("ent").value; alert(age); } </script> </body> </html>
```

Please modify your code as per I've given here. In your code the age value just collecting value at the start of page but tou need to get value after putting data

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, reflect any change to the input field in the variable as soon as the user inputs anything:

```html
<input type="number" id="ent" oninput="window.age = this.value" >
<button id="press" onclick="alert(window.age)">seed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't initialized your input with a value...

```
 <input type="number" value="80" id="ent">
```

Second, you can delete all your JS and just inline it directly in the button...

```
 <button id="press" onclick="alert(ent.value);">seed</button>
```

Comment: i wanted the value to be entered in the input box through the browser itself

Comment: It doesn't matter, you must ALWAYS initialize even with a zero!

Comment: @user4723924 you do not need to have an initial value. Please test out your code before stating such a strong statement